# Flag menu submenu indication

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-interface, flag-dialog

I recently faced the problem of not finding the flag I was looking for.

Specifically I was looking for the "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" flag. (Which can be found under "Needs improvement" -> "A community-specific reason" -> "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo").

I knew from questions that were closed because of that flag reason that it has to be somewhere, I just wasn't able to find it.

But the main reason I was not able to figure out where its hidden was not the depth of the flag menu itself but the fact that there is no indication of which flag will lead into another, deeper and more specific section of flags (like "needs improvement" and "A community-specific reason" do).

Therefore I did not click that deep into the flag menu and missed the "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" Flag.

**Problem summary**

No indication of opening submenu in the flag menu.

**Possible fix**

Add an arrow or any other visual indication.

Almost everywhere in the web where something opens we indicate it. Like accordion arrows, menu burgers etc. That behaviour is known by heart for users on the web. So is the assumption of something not opening if there's none of that indicators.

Adding an indicator would improve the user experience when using the flag menu a lot.

Comment: Related FR of mine on Meta.SE: [Why are the "off-topic" flag options (including "blatantly off-topic") listed under "needs improvement"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351279/348196)

Comment: There used to be an ellipse which (barely) indicated that there was an additional page of options available after selecting that one (and other selections). Unfortunately, that ellipse was, for some reason, designed out in the most recent major redesign of the close-vote reasons.